# zlib Compression Error

Tags: c, compression, zlib

I'm using this code snippet which I grabbed from a tutorial. It's meant to compress the data from an input file and put it into the output file. However, it gives a segmentation fault when running though:

```
int map_Compress(char *inmapfile, char *outmapfile)
{
    FILE *infile = fopen(inmapfile, "rb");
    gzFile outfile = gzopen(outmapfile, "wb");
    if (!infile || !outfile) return -1;
    char inbuffer[1];
    int num_read = 0;
    unsigned long total_read = 0;
    while ((num_read = fread(&inbuffer, 1, sizeof(inbuffer), infile)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n",total_read);
        total_read += num_read;
        gzwrite(outfile, inbuffer, num_read);
    }
    fclose(infile);
    gzclose(outfile);
    return total_read;
}
```

And it's being called like this:

```
int main()
{
    if (map_Compress("maps/main.map", "maps/main.mz") < 0)
    {
        printf("Compression failed, couldn't open file(s)\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What's with this segfault? All I see on the screen when this is called is:

```
0
1
```

And then the program crashes... What's going wrong here? My input file has some garbage content that I put in there, so shouldn't the function be compressing the data into the output file?

Please help, I'm sure it's a simple problem I've overlooked :)

Comment: So you intend to read the file 1 byte at a time? you may want to size that buffer up a touch (`unsigned char in buffer[1024];` for example).

Comment: The `printf()` conversion specifier does not match, what is being passed in. `num_read` and `total_read`shall be declared of `size_t`.

Comment: The code runs fine here. Most propably you witness a mal function due to something bad which happend before the call to `map_Compress()`.

Comment: ^^No, the 1 byte was just for testing :)

Comment: This problem persists to frustrate me, I cannot get it to go away...

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the code shown that would cause a crash.  It must be happening elsewhere.  Don't you have a debugger to show you where it crashed?

There are several minor things to be fixed.  For portability, `infile` should be compared to `NULL` and `outfile` should be compared to `Z_NULL`, instead of using `!`.  If the `fopen()` fails and the `gzopen()` succeeds, you should `gzclose()` on the error return to avoid a giant memory leak.  And vice versa.  The `printf` format should be `%lu`.  (You need to crank up your compiler warnings level a little.)  The `printf` should probably be after the addition to `total_read`, since the last number printed will not be the actual number read otherwise.  `map_compress()` should return an `unsigned long`, not an `int`, since you are returning `total_read`.  You have an extraneous `&` in the `fread()` — doesn't hurt, but can confuse, and would cause a failure if you changed `inbuffer` to an allocated buffer.

Your code is properly rigged to support a larger input buffer than one byte.  For efficiency, it should be much larger.  At least 4K or 8K.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that. I changed by buffer to 1 byte on purpose as a test because 128 bytes wasn't working. I was always going to change it :) Thanks for those tips....

Comment: map_compress() shouldn't return an unsigned long, as I return -1 for a failure :P But I understand that it really should match the variable I'm returning

Answer (score -3):

instead of

```
fread(&inbuffer, 1
```

try

```
fread(inbuffer, 1
```

Here:

```
gzwrite(outfile, inbuffer, num_read);
```

I don't know what this func do, but probably you trying to read num_read bytes from inbuffer, which contains only one byte.

Comment: The '&' shouldn't and doesn't make a difference. It dosen't matter how many bytes are in the buffer.

Comment: '&' also does not makes a sense there